# Python - create matrix of tuples

Tags: python, matrix, tuples

I need to create a 9x9 matrix of tuples. I already have a code:

```py
squares, sub = [], []
for y in [3, 6, 9]:
    sub.append([[(y, x) for x in range(1, 10) if x % 3 == 0] for x in range(1, 10) if x % 3 == 0])

for i in sub:
    sq = []
    for j in i:
        sq.extend(j)
    sq.sort()
    squares.append(sq)
    squares.append(sq)
    squares.append(sq)
```

with such result:

```
[[(3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 6), (3, 6), (3, 6), (3, 9), (3, 9), (3, 9)],
 [(3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 6), (3, 6), (3, 6), (3, 9), (3, 9), (3, 9)],
 [(3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 6), (3, 6), (3, 6), (3, 9), (3, 9), (3, 9)],
 [(6, 3), (6, 3), (6, 3), (6, 6), (6, 6), (6, 6), (6, 9), (6, 9), (6, 9)],
 [(6, 3), (6, 3), (6, 3), (6, 6), (6, 6), (6, 6), (6, 9), (6, 9), (6, 9)],
 [(6, 3), (6, 3), (6, 3), (6, 6), (6, 6), (6, 6), (6, 9), (6, 9), (6, 9)],
 [(9, 3), (9, 3), (9, 3), (9, 6), (9, 6), (9, 6), (9, 9), (9, 9), (9, 9)],
 [(9, 3), (9, 3), (9, 3), (9, 6), (9, 6), (9, 6), (9, 9), (9, 9), (9, 9)],
 [(9, 3), (9, 3), (9, 3), (9, 6), (9, 6), (9, 6), (9, 9), (9, 9), (9, 9)]]
```

Result is exactly as I want it to be, but do you think there is a better way to write it? Can it be done simpler?

#### Edit:

Result should be always identical, there isn't any dynamic input and it won't be edited afterwards. Just a static matrix used in a different part of my code.

Comment: Are the tuples always going to be these values or is there going to be an application with input of some sort? If they are fixed, list comprehension would work:
`[[(3*(i//3+1),3*(j//3+1)) for j in range(9)] for i in range(9)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear, as the final list (and the code) might be interpreted, and there might be multiple interpretations with the same result.

For one such interpretation, you could use a (twisted and kind of funny looking) nested list comprehension ([[Python 3.Docs]: Data Structures - List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)):

> ```py
> >>> from pprint import pprint as pp  # For print purposes only
> >>>
> >>> l = [3, 6, 9]
> >>>
> >>> items = [[i0 for i1 in l for i0 in ((i2, i1),) * len(l)] for i2 in l for _ in l]
> >>>
> >>> pp(items)
> [[(3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 6), (3, 6), (3, 6), (3, 9), (3, 9), (3, 9)],
>  [(3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 6), (3, 6), (3, 6), (3, 9), (3, 9), (3, 9)],
>  [(3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 3), (3, 6), (3, 6), (3, 6), (3, 9), (3, 9), (3, 9)],
>  [(6, 3), (6, 3), (6, 3), (6, 6), (6, 6), (6, 6), (6, 9), (6, 9), (6, 9)],
>  [(6, 3), (6, 3), (6, 3), (6, 6), (6, 6), (6, 6), (6, 9), (6, 9), (6, 9)],
>  [(6, 3), (6, 3), (6, 3), (6, 6), (6, 6), (6, 6), (6, 9), (6, 9), (6, 9)],
>  [(9, 3), (9, 3), (9, 3), (9, 6), (9, 6), (9, 6), (9, 9), (9, 9), (9, 9)],
>  [(9, 3), (9, 3), (9, 3), (9, 6), (9, 6), (9, 6), (9, 9), (9, 9), (9, 9)],
>  [(9, 3), (9, 3), (9, 3), (9, 6), (9, 6), (9, 6), (9, 9), (9, 9), (9, 9)]]
> ```

Note: Attempting to modify your final list (`squares[0][0] = 1`) might yield "unexpected" results.